# How to replace a dependency in a Grails project created with the GGTS/Eclipse?

Tags: grails, vaadin, dependency-management, vaadin7, hibernate-validator

I am new to Grails, I would like to ask someone how can I replace a dependency in a Grails project (using GGTS/Spring Tool Suite/Eclipse)?

Basically, I am asking this because of this issue I am experiencing while trying to use the Vaadin plugin for grails inside a Grails project (here is the issue on GitHub -> https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin/issues/48)

I have the following grails plugin which uses the `5.1.1.Final` version of the hibernate dependency (it takes it from my local .m2 Maven repository, below a snippet from `grails dependency-report`).

Hibernate:

```
+--- org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.6.1
    |    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.1.Final
```

Additionally, I also use the [vaadin plugin for grails](http://grails.org/plugin/vaadin):

Vaadin plugin for Grails:

```
org.grails.plugins:vaadin:7.3.9
|    \--- com.vaadin:vaadin-client:7.3.9
|         \--- com.vaadin:vaadin-shared:7.3.9
|              \--- com.vaadin.external.flute:flute:1.3.0.gg2
|              \--- com.vaadin.external.streamhtmlparser:streamhtmlparser-jsilver:0.0.10.vaadin1
|              \--- com.vaadin.external.google:guava:16.0.1.vaadin1
|              \--- com.vaadin.external.json:json:0.0.20080701
|         \--- org.w3c.css:sac:1.3
|         \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA
|         \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA
```

Here the plugin entries inside the `BuildConfig.groovy` file:

```
plugins {
    ...
    // this is the line I added
    compile ":vaadin:7.3.9"
    ...
    // This line is created automatically by the new project wizard
    runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"        
}
```

Now as you seen, the Vaadin plugin uses `javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA` but the Hibernate version used by grails by default is the latest one (5.1.1.Final) which is in turn incompatible with `javax.validation:validation-api:1.0.0.GA`. Instead either a downgrade to version *4.x.x* of hibernate-validator or an upgrade of the javax.validation library from `validation-api:1.0.0.GA` to `validation-api:1.1.0.Final` should be made.

I have found that I can switch the version of the Hibernate grails plugin (as it is advised inside BuildConfig.groovy):

```
 plugins {
        ...
        // this is the line I added
        compile ":vaadin:7.3.9"
        ...            
        runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.18" // instead of default ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1"
 }
```

This effectively installs `Hibernate 3 for Grails` which uses `hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final` instead of `5.1.1.Final`, therefore it should be compatible with javax.validation 1.0.0, but I still get the error for which I opened the issue on GitHub linked at the start of this question.

Now, as Hibernate 3 for Grails uses `4.1.0.Final` I can only think that I can try with `hibernate-validator-4.3.1.Final` (I have downloaded the .jar) to see what happens or someway replace `validation-api:1.0.0.GA` installed with the Vaadin Grails plugin and try again with Hibernate *5.1.1.Final*.

But how can I safely replace these dependencies without broke anything?
Or, even better, did someone experience the same problem with the Vaadin plugin for Grails and did you come with a better solution?

Thanks for the attention. Hope to resolve this trivial issue once for all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a comment of a user on the same issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin/issues/48#issuecomment-77685018

I resolved by replacing `runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.6.1"` with a bit older version `runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5"` and it works.